# Rails routing - versioning pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

i've built a page which routes `/locale/page` actually pretty simple stuff.

```
# current frontend routes
# allows urls like /en/im-an-awesome-page
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /([a-zA-Z]{2}[-_])?[a-zA-Z]{2}/ do
  get '/*path' => 'pages#show', as: 'page'
end
```

now i added the ability to add different versions of the page. the best thing would be if i don't have to change a lot of the routing or views. i would like to use same layout for every version.

url schema could be like: `/version1/en/im-an-awesome-page`

another possibility: `/versions/1/en/im-an-awesome-page`

tried this but i'm on a dead end if i call it without any version, the **page should show up without any version** attached as well (which then just shows the latest version).

```
# needed frontend routes
# allows urls like /en/im-an-awesome-page
# NEW also allows urls like /version-1/en/im-an-awesome-page
scope ":version", defaults: { version: '' } do
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /([a-zA-Z]{2}[-_])?[a-zA-Z]{2}/ do
    get '/*path' => 'pages#show', as: 'page'
  end
end
```

i'm pretty lost on this - any help would be awesome!

**EDIT: the page tree (whole url infrastructure) is different by every version**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
scope "(version/:version)", defaults: { version: 'latest' } do
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /([a-zA-Z]{2}[-_])?[a-zA-Z]{2}/ do
    get '/*path' => 'pages#show', as: 'page'
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  #...
  def show
    if params[:version] == 'latest'
      # find page by 'path' and max version
    else
      # find page by 'path' and params[:version]
    end
  end
end
```

You should get specific versioned page with this url: http://localhost:3000/version/1/en/the-page

and the latest with:
http://localhost:3000/en/the-page

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for :) thanks!! the ( ) makes it optional - right?

Comment: Yes, the parentheses makes a parameter optional. Also you may want to remove them from the ':local' scope and set a default value too.

Comment: perfect thankts - theres one problem... scope defaults override default_url_options - do you have an idea how to set it otherwise?

Comment: removed the defaults from scope and added a check to default_url_options (if version not present set nil) - now its all good thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want `/version/1/en/im-an-awesome-page`

I think you'd be better putting the version *at the end*: `/en/im-an-awesome-page/version/1`

---

This way you can have the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /([a-zA-Z]{2}[-_])?[a-zA-Z]{2}/ do
   resources :pages, path: "", only: :show do #-> url.com/en/:page_id
      get "version/:version", on: :member #-> url.com/en/:page_id/version/:version
   end
end
```

This will provide functionality to access the "page" on its own and also with a version.

The difference will be that you could run with the latest version if no `:version` param is defined:

```
#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesContorller < ApplicationController
   def show
      @page = Page.find params[:id]
      if params[:version]
         ...
      else
         ...
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! that sounds good so far but theres one problem with this solution... the tree is different by version

Comment: What do you mean? The solution should work. I can amend if you explain your situation

Comment: a version is a version of the whole page... so there can be a /v1/en/my-page which is non existent in /v2/en/my-page would throw a 404.. hope this explanation is better :)

Comment: Right, so is it the version for your *app* or your *page*? My recommendation provides for no version - it works just as you need.

Comment: its for the whole app... imagine a clothing brand page where the regular customer sees the normal page with the current collection of stuff.. and the distributor can see the stuff for next year just with a prefix of the url like the version...

Comment: Okay, this should have been explained in the original question, it's a complete infrastructure change. I figured you wanted the version of the page alone???

Comment: exactly - sorry for my weird explanation

Comment: lol it's okay. Do you still want me to have a crack at fixing it?